# ViewState not working in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having trouble with ViewState.

I have enabled ViewState for all controls in my Form.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    onselectedindexchanged="Period_Changed" ontextchanged="Period_Changed" 

    style="top: 238px; left: 1038px; position: absolute; height: 22px; width: 77px; z-index: 104">
    <asp:ListItem>Today</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3 Days</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>7 Days</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Year</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Called method

```
protected void Period_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string periodTxt = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    ViewState["Period"] = periodTxt;            
}
```

But ViewState does not have the new value when Page_Load is called at a later stage.

```
protected void ZedGraphWeb1_RenderGraph1(ZedGraph.Web.ZedGraphWeb webObject, Graphics g, MasterPane pane)
{
                if (ViewState["Period"] == null)
    {
        ViewState["Period"] = "Today";
    }
    else
    {
        periodTxt = ViewState["Period"].ToString();
    }
 }
```

Comment: have you placed breakpoint ? any errors there?

Comment: what is the value of `EnableViewState` on your page?

Comment: There is no error. ViewState just does not have the previous value... And yes ViewState is enabled at the top of the .aspx

Comment: may be this is because of missing IsPostBack on page load event?

Comment: "Page_Load is called at a later stage" - is this because of a postback (should work) or a redirect (will NOT work)? ViewState is kept in a hidden field on the page - it requires a POST to be sent from the browser / be available again on the server.

Comment: @HansKesting So how to I reference ViewState changes originated by the PostBack, when a later Page_Load runs? I want to keep the ViewState change.

Comment: It sounds like you need to store things in `Session` instead of `ViewState`

Comment: @HansKesting Can you point me at  simple example? If you look at code in Question I appear to be using ViewState...

Comment: You seem to be trying to use ViewState in a scenario where that does not apply. Try replacing all `ViewState["Period"]` with `Session["Period"]`